# Http Read timeouts on query calls to Elastic Search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, httpclient, elasticsearch-jest

I'm troubleshooting an issue with our application hosted in K8s pod, which tries to query ES cluster through ES Jest Client. Most of the queries were successful, but randomly a call fails with read timeout. Any help will be appreciated.

**Jest Client version:6.3.1**

**ES cluster is hosted in AWS**

Below i'm providing apache http debug logs.

> ````
> o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context 
> o.a.h.i.c.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route
> {}->http://dev-app-elasticsearch-lb.xyz.com:9200  
> o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request POST
> /_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&preference=_primary_first
> HTTP/1.1   o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state:
> UNCHALLENGED   o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state:
> UNCHALLENGED   org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-16 >> POST
> /_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&preference=_primary_first
> HTTP/1.1   org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-16 >>
> Content-Length: 2531   org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-16 >>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  
> org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-16 >> Host:
> dev-app-elasticsearch-lb.xyz.com:9200   org.apache.http.headers -
> http-outgoing-16 >> Connection: Keep-Alive   org.apache.http.headers -
> http-outgoing-16 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_181)
> org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-16 >> Accept-Encoding:
> gzip,deflate   org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >> "POST
> /_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&preference=_primary_first
> HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"   org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >>
> "Content-Length: 2531[\r][\n]"   org.apache.http.wire -
> http-outgoing-16 >> "Content-Type: application/json;
> charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"   org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >>
> "Host: dev-app-elasticsearch-lb.xyz.com:9200[\r][\n]"  
> org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >> "Connection:
> Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"   org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >>
> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_181)[\r][\n]"  
> org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >> "Accept-Encoding:
> gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"   org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >>
> "[\r][\n]"  org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-16 >> "{[\n]"
> ....<<outgoing query details>>  
> o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS  
> o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS  
> o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS  
> o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS  
> c.t.c.util.concurrent.DatabaseLock - Cleaning up expired locks from DS
> 0   o.a.h.i.c.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connection  
> o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-6: Close
> connection   o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing
> connections idle longer than 15 MINUTES 
> o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 15 MINUTES  
> o.a.h.i.n.c.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections
> idle longer than 15 MINUTES```
> ````

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Naresh

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Could you provide an answer in this case. Thanks